# Disable shipping in Magento?

Tags: shipping

Disable shipping in Magento
I need to create a catalog price quotation of products in store
And the store will not deliver the mails, so I need to disable the freight

Answer (score 1):

Hard to fully understand your question here, but if you are saying that the products are not shipped from the store so you dont want to charge shipping then the easiest way is to create them as virtual products.

Failing that then you should write some code that makes them pretend to be virtual products, this would have the least impact on the system. There is no way to switch off shipping.